# Regex to extract only text after string and before space

Tags: regex

I want to match text after given string.  In this case, the text for lines starting with "BookTitle" but before first space:

```
BookTitle:HarryPotter JK Rowling
BookTitle:HungerGames Suzanne Collins
Author:StephenieMeyer BookTitle:Twilight
```

Desired output is:

```
HarryPotter
HungerGames
```

I tried: `"^BookTitle(.*)"` but it's giving me matches where BookTitle: is in middle of line, and also all the stuff after white space.  Anyone help?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

you can have `positive lookbehind` in your pattern.

```
 (?<=BookTitle:).*?(?=\s)
```

For more info: [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Width Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: @user1899415 it will work on python. [Click here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/CyELE.jpg)

Answer (score 8):

What language is this?
And provide some code, please; with the `^` anchor you should definitely *only* be matching on string that *begin* with BookTitle, so something else is wrong.
If you can guarantee that all whitespace is stripped from the titles, as in your examples, then `^BookTitle:(\S+)` should work in many languages.
Explanation:
`^` requires the match to start at the beginning of the string, as you know.
`\s` - *lower*case means: match on white*s*pace (space, tab, etc.)
`\S` - *upper*case means the inverse: match on anything BUT whitespace.
`\w` is another possibility: match on *w*ord character (alphanumeric plus underscore) - but that will fail you if, for example, there's an apostrophe in the title.
`+`, as you know, is a quantifier meaning "at least one of".
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 5):

With the 'multi-line' regex option use something like this:

```
 ^BookTitle:([^\s]+)
```

Without multi-line option, this:

```
 (?:^|\n)BookTitle:([^\s]+)
```