# Using grep to display a particular value in command line

Tags: command-line, grep

i have to check a licence of a product which i can by just typing

```
checklicence
```

in commandline.

it gives me output:

```
Product License status

Parameters of license Sxxxxx--xxxxx--xxxxx4


Volume
    Regular texts
        Units: Pages
        Quantity: 120000 per year
        Remains: 107852 this year
```

i want to find just how many remain's are there and print that.

So i tried of doing

```
 >checklicense |grep -i "Remains:"
```

i am getting output as

```
>Remains: 107852 this year
```

But i just want the number `107852` as output

Is there any way how to do this?

my grep version is `License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3`

Comment: @Inian `License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3`

Comment: Find my answer below and let me know if it solved your problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex to extract only text after string and before space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18709439/regex-to-extract-only-text-after-string-and-before-space)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `-P` flag from the `GNU grep` along with the `-o` flag to match only the part we are looking for,

```
checklicence | grep -oP 'Remains:\s\K([^ ]\d+)'
107852
```

The `-P` flag in `GNU grep` is to enable the [Perl Compatible Regular Expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions)
 library.

> \K: [This sequence resets the starting point of the reported match. Any previously matched characters are not included in the final matched sequence.](http://www.phpfreaks.com/blog/pcre-regex-spotlight-k)

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/RwhQOL/1)

---

Also worth adding that the `man grep` page says

> This is highly experimental and `grep -P` may warn of unimplemented features.

Answer (score 1):

```
Checklicense |grep -i "Remains:" | grep -o "[0-9]*"
```

This would get only the numeric part of the the result of the first grep

Comment: what does grep -o do?

Comment: -o display the part only matching a specific format ,since only numeric is required [0-9]* wildcards