# SQL group by middle part of string

Tags: sql, string, hadoop, group-by

I have string column that looks usually approximately like this:

```
https://mapy.cz/zakladni?x=16.3360208&y=49.6718038&z=8&source=firm&id=13123554
https://mapy.cz/turisticka?x=15.9380354&y=50.1990211&z=11&source=base&id=2197
https://mapy.cz/turisticka?x=12.8611357&y=49.8051338&z=16&source=base&id=1703157
```

I would like to group data by **source** which is part of the string - four letters behind "source=" (in the case above: `firm`) and then simply count them. Is there a way to achieve this directly in SQL code? I am using hadoop.

Data is a set of strings that look like above. My expected result is summary table with two columns: 1) Each type of the source (there is about 20 possible and their length is different so I cannot use sipmle substring). Ideally I am looking for solution that says: For the grouping use four letters that come after "source=" 2) Count of their occurences in all the strings.

There is just one source type in each string.

Comment: Can you add to your question which database server you're using (PostgreSQL, MySQL, SQLite...)?

Comment: Count what? The letters in firm, or the number of sources in a value? Or the number of source in a whole table?

Comment: @WanderNauta Edited. I am using hadoop.

Comment: @jarlh count occurences of each source

Comment: Show us some more sample data, and also the expected result. (Make it easy to assist you!)

Comment: @jarlh tried to update it a bit more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `regexp_extract()`:

```
select substr(regexp_extract(url, 'source[^&]+'), 8)
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was looking for! Meanwhile I got to similar answer that extracts only the text after "source" and before "&" using positive lookbehind: `(?<=source=).*?(?=\&)`. Credits to this question: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18709439/regex-to-extract-only-text-after-string-and-before-space]

Answer (score 0):

You can use charindex in MSSQL to get position of string and extract record

```
;with cte as (
SELECT SUBSTRING('https://mapy.cz/zakladni?x=16.3360208&y=49.6718038&z=8&source=firm&id=13123554',
                  charindex('&source=','https://mapy.cz/zakladni?x=16.3360208&y=49.6718038&z=8&source=firm&id=13123554')
                  +8,4) AS ExtractString ) 
                  
select ExtractString,count(ExtractString) as count from cte group by ExtractString;
```

There is equivalent function LOCATE in hiveql for charindex.

Comment: Thenk you. Unfortunately the strings have different length so I cannot use simple position. I am looking for this ideally: For the grouping use 4 letters that come in the string after "source=".

Comment: Initial length of string till  "&source=" doesn't matter. CHARINDEX or LOCATE will give you first occurring starting position of "&source=", you can get that position and pass it to SUBSTRING function as position to start substring.

Comment: I tested your solution and it seems valid for other syntax but in case of Hive Hadoop there seems to be problem with `CHARINDEX` function. I found out this should do the trick in Hadoop: `SUBSTRING(url, INSTR(url, '&source=')+8,4)`