# Python separate lines into sheet

Tags: python

I'm writing a simple Python script to read screenshots of receipts, and if the screenshot detects a line with numbers on it, to put that into a new row in a CSV. So for example:

```
text = ...
for line in text:
    cell_name, money = splitThisIntoCells(line)
    f.write(cell_name + "," + money + "\n")
```

So that if it reads, let's say:

> Trip fare: $2

It will place this into a spreadsheet row with the first cell being "Trip fare" and the second cell being "$2" or "2".

How can I write this splitting logic?

Comment: If you have allways a dollor sign `$` you could use `Trip fare: $2`.split('$') or `line.split('$')`. If this is not the case you have to find a more complex solution.

Comment: You can use regex for this situation. Check out this thread -- [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18709439/regex-to-extract-only-text-after-string-and-before-space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18709439/regex-to-extract-only-text-after-string-and-before-space)